# Javascript onclick events for css elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a css element to invert the whole website as in dark-mode...i was able to use a keycode to toggle the css element and it worked perfectly fine....but the issue is that i want to use a button to toggle the element

css >

```
.dark-mode{
    filter: invert(1) hue-rotate(180deg)
}

.invert{
    filter: invert(1) hue-rotate(180deg)
}
```

Javascript >

```
    document.onkeypress = function (e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        
        if(e.keyCode === 13){
            document.documentElement.classList.toggle('dark-mode');
            
            document.querySelectorAll('.inverted').forEach((result) => {
                result.classList.toggle('invert');
            })
        }
    }
```

these codes works fine but i want to use a button to toggle it.....

Comment: Give the button a `click` event listener that does the same thing.

Comment: am a kid new to programing...I've done every posiible research on this but still could not find an answer....if i could get a javascript code with html....

Comment: What is a "css element"? Do you mean a CSS rule?

Answer (score 0):

```
<buton onclick="invert()" > Invert </button>
```

Use the same function with the one you wrote for invert()

Answer (score 0):

Put the toggle code into a named function. Then call it from the keypress listener and also a click listener on the button.

```js
function toggle_scheme() {
  document.documentElement.classList.toggle('dark-mode');

  document.querySelectorAll('.inverted').forEach((result) => {
    result.classList.toggle('invert');
  })
}

document.querySelector("toggle-scheme").addEventListener("click", toggle_scheme);

document.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    toggle_scheme();
  }
});
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept answers that solve the problem. Click on the check mark next to the answer.